# Is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with determinant $1$ an open subset of $M(n,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with determinant $1$ an open ,dense connected subset of $M(n,\mathbb R) $ i.e set of all matrices over $\mathbb R$?

I know it will be a closed subset of $M(n,\mathbb R)$,not bounded and hence not compact.But not sure about the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ has determinant one, then $p(s) = \det (A-sI)$ is a non-constant polynomial, hence we can find arbitrarily small $s$ such that $p(s) \neq 1$. Hence the space is not open.

The function $A \mapsto \det A$ is continuous, hence, for example, $2I$ has a neighbourhood in which $\det A \neq 1$.

One way of showing that the space is connected (in fact, path connected) is to
show a path between $I$ and the matrix.

Comment: density is clear,but I cant get the idea for open ness

Comment: If it was open, then you could find a small ball around each element such that the determinant was one. The first sentence above shows that this is not possible.

Comment: thanks @copper for explaining

Comment: You are welcome. I thought I had a clean way of showing connectedness, but it became very messy (I forgot I had to deal with complex eigenvalues). Basically you can use the (real) Jordan form and some messy paths to show that there is a path from any matrix with determinant one and $I$.

Answer (score 1):

If it were open and closed, then $M(n,\mathbb R)$ would not be connected – but it is.

Comment: How to prove $M(n,\mathbb R)$ connected?

Comment: @learningmaths, $M(n,\mathbb R) = \mathbb R^{n^2}$.